# Loop a sound file from a certain point?

Tags: java, loops, audio, javasound

Suppose I have a sound file that I wish to play in this manner:

1. Start from the 0:00 mark.
2. When the sound file ends, replay from the 0:30.00 mark.

Essentially, I wish for the song to play from 0:00 to 0:30, then loop from 0:30 to the end.

How do you do this?

Usually, when playing Audio Files, I use AudioClip.

```
AudioClip audio = Applet.newAudioClip( this.getClass().getResource( "..." ) );
audio.loop();
```

It's because of bad experiences with loading the audio file when the project is packed into a .jar file. If the method you recommend uses another class, I would still be more than happy to listen. However, if you've encountered the same problem as I have and know how to fix it, please do tell me.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a `Clip` for this, or if the clip is too large, feed the bytes directly to a [`SourceDataLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/SourceDataLine.html).

Comment: I put an example of using a `Clip` on the JavaSound info. page (chase the links from the tag above). As to further examples, what is your budget?